# Should I use string.Contains() before string.Replace()?

Tags: c#, .net

Is it unnecessary to have this if statement before doing a string replace?

```
 if (myString.Contains(oldValue))
 {
      myString = myString.Replace(oldValue, newValue);
 }
```

Comment: Try it without and find out.

Comment: The latest Visual Studio has an interactive C# prompt that's perfect for experimenting: `View -> Other Windows -> C# Interactive`

Comment: To add to @adv12's point, what did you find when you tried it that left you still having a question about this? Or if you didn't try it yourself already, what was it that prevented you from doing so.

Comment: @adv12: You cannot deduce the documented contract by *"trying it out"*.

Comment: @IInspectable - I suspect you can in this case. Why don't you think so?

Comment: @Enigmativity: Consider a hypothetical specification, that states, that the result is unspecified in case *oldValue* doesn't exist. How would you deduce this by trying it out? And what about the return value? Does it always return a new instance? Does it occasionally return the same instance? Trying it out will only produce details about a particular **implementation**, not the guaranteed contract. Suggesting to give it a try is terrible advice, even though it doesn't hurt as much/often with .NET as it does with other platforms.

Comment: @IInspectable - That certainly sounds plausible, but the OP is trying to understand this particular implementation. And even if the implementation were the result of a vague spec it is now the status quo - Microsoft will never change it - so you can assume that the implementation is now the spec.

Comment: @Enigmativity: The OP is asking for contractual guarantees, not coincidential implementation details. The contract is free to impose or relax any number of restrictions, something you cannot deduce by trying it out. One such restriction is, that the same instance (vs. a copy) is returned, in case *oldValue* is not found. You cannot know, if this restriction is contractual, unless you consult the documentation.

Comment: @IInspectable - I don't see anything in the question specifically asking for contractual guarantees. You may see it, but I don't, so I guess this becomes a matter of opinion.

Comment: @Enigmativity: The OP is clearly asking, **unconditionally**, whether the `if`-statement is required. It doesn't take any reading-into to take that for what it is: A question asking for contractual guarantees. If the question were stated along the lines of *"Given the implementation currently shipping with .NET v4.5.2, would dropping the `if`-statement be safe?"*, you might have a point. But even then, you'd need a big fat disclaimer, saying: *"Answering this question is opening the passage to faith-based programming"*.

Comment: @IInspectable - Again, I don't see it that way. Shall we agree to disagree?

Comment: @Enigmativity: Why are you needlessly arguing for a position, that is so blatantly wrong? Trying it out (when contractual documentation is readily available) has not ever been an option, much less would it be the first thing that comes to mind, when no specifics are requested. I'm ending this useless debate at this point. If you believe you have anything useful to say, you get the last word.

Comment: @IInspectable - This has been a matter of opinion. I don't see anything that is "clearly", "unconditional", "blatantly", etc. You're throwing around a lot of hyperbole and nothing that directly supports your argument nor refutes mine that is based on anything in the OP's question. I've been trying to close this conversation in the last two rounds.

Comment: Well this has surely been entertaining. Thank you both for your help, it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: My understanding that question was asked regarding if this additional statement improve/worse or not changing performance of the code.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

All the details are in the documentation for [String.Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx):

> Return Value:
>   A string that is equivalent to the current string except that all instances of *oldValue* are replaced with *newValue*. **If *oldValue* is not found in the current instance, the method returns the current instance unchanged.**

The `if` statement is not required.

An `if` statement is not even a performance optimization, since `String.Replace` returns the same object instance, if *oldValue* is not found. I have verified this using the following code:

```
namespace StringReplaceTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string s = "Test";
            string s2 = s.Replace("Foo", "Bar");
            string s3 = s.Replace("es", "tt");
        }
    }
}
```

Using the handy *Make Object ID* feature (right-click on a symbol in the *Locals*, *Auto*, or *Watch* window; see [Common Expression Evaluator Features](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms164903.aspx) for more details) produced the following output:

```
s  | "Test" {$1}
s2 | "Test" {$1}
s3 | "Tttt" {$2}
```

Comment: The quoted ReferenceSource comment only applies if `oldValue` is found. `StringBuilder` is mutated by the `Replace` call. `string` cannot be mutated using safe code, so a new instance has to be allocated. The first part of your answer is correct (tested using .NET 4.5.1). If `oldValue` is not found, the same, original instance is returned for both interned and non-interned strings.

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy: The seemingly disagreeing information caught my curiosity. I checked the behavior, and came to the same conclusion you posted in your comment.

Comment: This is a great answer. I request the OP to accept this answer instead of mine. *Really*, mine is just two or three lines. This is a much more elaborate answer.

Comment: The question is on performance, not possibility.  Is it more performant to do a contains then replace, vs just replace.  My guess is that you may as well do the replace, since if the oldValue isn't found, the contains and the replace will have had to search the whole string anyways.

Answer (score 4):

Since the `String.Replace()` function doesn't throw an exception if the string doesn't contain the value specified, it's unnecessary to verify it. It will go through an unnecessary condition.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but just wanted to provide my 2¢!

*Please, let me know if what I'm saying is wrong, but I just tried it on my environment and seemed plausible! :)*

For the most part, yes, the replace function will do the contains for you therefore it's unnecessary to have it separately. However, it is advantageous to do so if your "new value" is derived from a method - depending on how much work is done to get that value within the method!

Example when it ***not*** advantageous:
I'm working on making "String Replacers" for the body of an email sent by an application. For example, if the user has "[[User Name]]" within the body of the email, I want to replace that with the recipients first name. Thankfully, our framework has that information stored in memory, so I don't mind doing a single replace for that.

Example when it ***is*** advantageous:
Under the same premise from above, another replacer is "[[Payments]]". This would go to the database, and bring up a log of the top 1000 transactions the user made, then do some work on the data retrieved and show details on the body of the email. Imagine having to do all of that every time the user sends an email from the app, even if it doesn't contain the "[[Payments]]" keyword! Having the contains before calling my method that comes up with the string value of "[[Payments]]" really pays off here!

Long story short, it depends on your implementation, but for the most part - yes, it's unnecessary.

Comment: This is an answer to a different question: "Should I avoid unneeded costly calculations?"

Comment: The point is that the Replace method will evaluate the newValue even if it doesn't end up using it, so better check if it contains a match before doing the replace if the newValue is an expensive operation.

Answer (score -3):

In me experience, if you will replace many time (and you need one replace) better checking with Contains(). In my case is help my code be more fast (almost doubled).